# Seeding Data from JSON API to Ruby on Rails APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, database

I'm getting a `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` error that has me stumped, and unable to import user records and seed my database with them.

So far I have no problem accessing the data, but receive an error referencing the '[]' on the line with `User.find...` on it

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'faker'

#this script imports APR user data from the zendesk api and populates 
the database with it. 


uri = URI.parse("https://blahsupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.basic_auth("blah@blah.com", "blahpass")

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

@response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
puts @response.body
puts @response.message
puts @response.code

info = @response.body 

info.force_encoding("utf-8")

File.write('blahusers1.json', info)


puts "File Created Successfully!"

file = File.read('blahusers1.json')

users = JSON.load(file)

users.each do |a|
    User.find_or_create_by_zendesk_id(:zendesk_id => a['id'], :url => a['url'], :name => a['name'], :email => a['email'])
end
```

Any ideas on how I've gotten this error? Thank you for any help!

**Edit

Below is an example of the data being returned.

```
{"users":[{"id":333653859,"url":"https://blahblah.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/333653859.json","name":"Randy Blah","email":"randy@blah.com","created_at":"2014-08-06T14:31:24Z","updated_at":"2018-04-04T14:22:06Z","time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","phone":null,"shared_phone_number":null,"photo":{"url":"https://aprtechsupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/attachments/68955389.json","id":68955389,"file_name":"Work.jpg","content_url":"https://aprtechsupport.zendesk.com/system/photos/6895/5389/Work.jpg","mapped_content_url":"https://blahblah.zendesk.com/system/photos/6895/5389/Work.jpg","content_type":"image/jpeg","size":2528,"width":80,"height":80,"inline":false,"thumbnails":[{"url":"https://blahblah.zendesk.com/api/v2/attachments/68955399.json","id":68955399,"file_name":"Work_thumb.jpg","content_url":"https://blahblah.zendesk.com/system/photos/6895/5389/Work_thumb.jpg","mapped_content_url":"https://blahblah.zendesk.com/system/photos/6895/5389/Work_thumb.jpg","content_type":"image/jpeg","size":2522,"width":32,"height":32,"inline":false}]},"locale_id":1,"locale":"en-US","organization_id":null,"role":"admin","verified":true,"external_id":null,"tags":[],"alias":"","active":true,"shared":false,"shared_agent":false,"last_login_at":"2018-04-04T14:21:44Z","two_factor_auth_enabled":null,"signature":"Thanks for contacting the helpdesk!\n-Randy","details":"","notes":"","role_type":null,"custom_role_id":null,"moderator":true,"ticket_restriction":null,"only_private_comments":false,"restricted_agent":false,"suspended":false,"chat_only":false,"default_group_id":21692179,"user_fields":{}}
```

Comment: Give us an example of what the content of blahusers1.json is (because 
 the script that you've given produces `{"error":"Couldn't authenticate you"}` ? 

And the backtrace of the error too?

Comment: Example provided in Edit!

Comment: See whether my answer helps you solve/understand the problem.

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example data you posted has a root object `users` that contains the array of user objects. So when you loop users using `users.each`, `a` is actually an `Array` and not a user `Hash` like you expected.

When you try to access an element of an `Array` using a 'String' index, it gives you the exception – `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

So, try changing

```
users = JSON.load(file)
```

to

```
users = JSON.load(file)['users']
```

to get it working like how you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you hallucinations! That was the issue and it worked. I upvoted, but as I have less than fifteen rep it won't display on the post.

Comment: No worries! However, when you have enough reputation, I would appreciate if you could please upvote my answer since it helped you.

Comment: I definitely will do.